# Should I resend an application to give a shorter resume?

Tags: professionalism, communication, resume, applications, canada

Almost 24 hours ago, I submitted an application for an engineering job through that company's email using a resume template that I used when I was applying for internships as a 3rd year university student (I am a recent graduate). It was a 2-page resume and some of my relatives who worked in HR said that it was too long and looked like a student resume. I have made some changes and shrunk it down to 1 page. Should I resend my application and hope that my old application was unread, and my new application would cover my old one?

Comment: When you say "relatives who work in HR" do you mean in HR for the company for which you applied - i.e. would they be the ones getting and reviewing your revamped resumé?

Comment: What do you have in your resume as a recent college graduate that makes it 2 pages long?  I've got close to 2 decades work experience as a software developer, plus 5 years in the Army before that and mine is not 2 full pages.

Comment: My resume is about.. 16 pages and I had in total more than 50 interviews the last 3 years. Well, I don't know whether I got rejected once because of that but the companies which invited me were quite good.

Comment: @Ben wait, 16 pages? Are you in a niche industry and those are mainly project names etc? I can't imagine having a resume over two pages without being superfluous.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### No you shouldn't.

2 pages is not excessive. It may be longer than the "optimum" length of resume, but it's very unlikely your resume will be thrown out just for being 2 pages. On the other hand submitting a resume a second time looks unprofessional - as though you had forgotten you had already applied for this job.

It is also making the company do extra work - they need to realize that you applied twice, go and find the original resume and delete it from their applications. Since the point of short resumes is not to make the recruiters do extra work, submitting two resumes defeats the original point.

Comment: If OP is called in for an interview/follow up, would it be appropriate then to perhaps mention something like "I have a shorter resume if you would like me to submit or bring that. I removed a few XYZ things"?  I do agree that two pages isn't bad and to most likely just let it be, but curious of your thoughts on suggesting you send a more succinct version when contacted.  (Granted if they got the longer resume and called for a follow up, they're more than likely fine with it)

Comment: No. If you've made it to the interview stage then the resume has done it's job. Interviewers probably want more info rather than less.

Answer (score 20):

If you re-send an application, this company will now have received in the span of 24 hours two applications from you with two separate resumes.  This will likely make you look like a disorganized and unprepared candidate and can hurt your chances of being considered for the role.

> Should I resend my application and hope that my new application was unread and my new application would cover my old one?

Personally I would not send a new application.  Also, I don't know why you would hope that any of your applications was not read.  If they don't read your first one, what guarantee is there that they read the new one?  And why would you want to work for a company that can't do something as simple as reading all the applications for their open positions?

Answer (score 10):

If the CV is up-to-date with your studies, experience, and profile, and you’re not aware of any serious mistakes on your resume, including any gaps, then do not re-apply for the same position and vacancy, especially within 24 hours after submitting your original application.
It can confuse their hiring team or even make you look unprofessional.
Regarding the resume’s length, the suggested page number is 2 pages maximum. But my CV is 5-6 pages, but I’m more comfortable in having a long CV than having gaps which might raise unnecessary suspicions.
I’ve had interviewers praise my CV, describing it as well written and my profile well-described, and was never given any negative feedback due to its length by them. It’s a matter of opinion and it goes both ways (the job applicant and the hiring personnel).

Comment: I only graduate this year, should I have such a long CV?

Comment: Just a heads-up: "longevity" only applies to length of life. Here "length" is correct.

Comment: @FaitoDayo no.  a long CV would be for someone with many years of experience as it would list different roles / responsibilities (as oxyrend says, so there's no "gaps" [in dates]).  The "core"/summary/at-a-glance part of the CV showing your skills should still be short even on an otherwise relatively long CV.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I resend an application to give a shorter resume?

No, this would cause more issues than it would solve.

The only time I've ever sent a second resume for a single position is when a recruiter asked for a resume tailored to the job position.

> It was a 2-page resume and some of my relatives who worked in HR said that it was too long

If you're applying for a frontline fast-food position then 2 pages is unusually lengthy, yes.

Engineering though, 2 pages seems about right. Length has never been a reason for me to reject a resume. However, if I skim it and it's 5 pages of crap then it does go in the garbage.

If your relative is putting this much emphasis on resume length then they are probably bad at their HR job.

> and looked like a student resume

This, this is an actionable item. If your resume is crafted like a newbie then you will be labeled as one.

Get samples of professional resumes in your field and see how you can improve your own.