# Should I follow up with my application email?

Tags: professionalism, communication, applications, email, canada

I am a master's student applying for a job that, on its description, doesn't require experience. I have sent an email to their "careers@XXX.ca" mailbox with my 2-page resume ([here is the related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187928/should-i-resend-an-application-to-give-a-shorter-resume)) 2 weeks ago. However, I haven't heard anything back, while the job is still open on its website and other job-finding websites. Should I email them again and ask for an update, or just to find out whether they have processed my application yet?

Also, since my currently focus is learning new stuff (hence I am in master's program) instead of making , should I also add in that "I am willing to work for less or no pay" or something like that?

Comment: Have you applied for an internship from your university career center ? That is one of the most common ways for college students to get the first job to earn work experience while still having a few semesters to complete at school.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I email them again and ask for an update, or just to find out
> whether they have processed my application yet?

If it's been two weeks, it is reasonable to contact them and ask if they received your application.

> Also, since my currently focus is learning new stuff (hence I am in
> master's program) instead of making , should I also add in that "I am
> willing to work for less or no pay" or something like that?

No. Good employers are looking for a good fit, not for the cheapest possible worker.

Advertising that you are free/inexpensive won't help you get a job with a good employer.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I email them again and ask for an update, or just to find out whether they have processed my application yet?

No, I don't think it is necessary to do so (even after 2 weeks).

Most likely, they already got your application. Now, it is up to them to contact either you or other candidates whom they may like better. Even if you email them to ask for an update, they will likely ignore your emails because they may have too many applicants and can't reply them all.

I would suggest that you should keep applying for other jobs either at that company or other companies. That is a better way of spending your time.

If a company think that you are a good fit, they will contact you and initiate an interview. There is no need for you to contact them after you already submit an application.